# Get data from certain date to last 10 days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to get data from certain date to last 10 days. I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
DECLARE @wrking_date DATE = '2022-02-08'
SELECT 
    a,
    CAST(LogDate as date) as theDate,
    b,c
FROM magic_table
Where b = '123'
AND @wrking_date >= DATEADD(DAY,10, GETDATE())
```

What I am doing wrong ?

## EDIT

I have also tried adding `AND LogDate between '2022-02-08' and DATEADD(DAY, -10, '2022-02-08')` this does not work

Comment: any error? can provide error msg, sample data, expected output?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Though I must admit, `AND @wrking_date >= DATEADD(DAY,10, GETDATE())` seems wrong; it doesn't reference a column in your table, but rather checks to see if the variable `@wrking_date` has a value greater or equal to the date and time in 10 days (so about `2022-09-16 09:11:17` (UTC) right now). So you'll get no result, as `2022-02-08` is *less* than `2022-09-16 09:11:17`.

Comment: Thanks  but how would you write it ?

Comment: You need to be clearer: "from certain date to last 10 days" means what? from that date for 10 days? Or from that date until 10 days back from today? Or from 10 days from that date until today?

Comment: This means if the working_date is  01.09.2022 then from 01.09 untll last 10 days *back* meaning from 22.08 -01-09

Comment: So from 10 days *before* that date until that date? How then does `GETDATE` come into the calculation, it seems irrelevant?

Comment: Okey, what will be the solution then ?

Comment: is it `LogDate between '2022-02-08' and DATEADD(DAY, -10, '2022-02-08')`

Comment: Nope that seems to be  an issue as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's currently written, your query doesn't get filtered with your `AND` condition because neither `GETDATE()` not `@wrking_date` are part of the queried table. I'm assuming you want to filter based on the column `LogDate`. To get the values between `@wrking_date` and 10 days ago, you can use `BETWEEN`:

```
AND LogDate BETWEEN @wrking_date AND DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())
```

Notice this: To get the date from 10 days ago, you need to use `-10` in the `DATEADD` function.

### Edit

As I got from your comments, you're trying to get the data between the defined `@working_date` and 10 days back from there. You could achieve that by using this:

```
AND LogDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -10, @wrking_date) AND @wrking_date
```

Comment: However I am getting more then 10 days data with it

Comment: So then you need to specify in your question what exactly you mean by `from certain date to last 10 days`. What is your expected outcome?

Comment: I thought it was clear enough. I need to retrive data from the `working_date` to last 10 days

Comment: What else could be understood from this statement ?

Comment: Yes and with my solution you would get all the rows where the `LogDate` is between your `@wrking_date` and the date that was 10 days ago. And because you're setting the `@wrking_date` to `2022-02-08`, you're getting data between `2022-02-08` and `2022-08-27`. That's what I understood from your question.

Comment: yes, but I getting more then that. I am getting data from 2022-04-09 as well

Comment: That's because 2022-04-09 is between 2022-02-08 and 2022-08-27.

Comment: I  can see there is a misunderstanding. If the selected date is 01.09, then I need to retrive data from 10 days back. meaning data between 22.08 -01-09

Comment: Thank you . I just figured it out as well. This one works